# What is the expected result to test when there are blank form fields?

Tags: manual-testing

What should be the expected result if I do not enter content in form field that are required?

When/how should the user be notified?

Comment: Login successful maybe ? anything is possible is depends on the system requirements, in general "This field is required" message when it is required or nothing when it is not.

Comment: what if that field is for saving a product name,and entering blank space and clicking on save should it save that blank name?

Comment: It wont be acceptable to me as a user, but still you might have a customer that wants it to be saved as a requirement.

Comment: Did my best to make it a salvageable question.

Answer (score 1):

**It depends.**

If you didn't enter anything and the field is optional, you should expect the empty field to be accepted.

If you didn't enter anything and the field is required, you should expect an error message.

If you entered a non-printable character such as <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and this is valid input, you should expect the field to be accepted.

If you entered a non-printable character such as <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and this is not valid input, you should expect the field an error message.

First check what the documentation of your application says the field is supposed to accept, then expect the field's behavior to match the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

***What should be the expected result if I do not enter content in form field that are required?***

- It is not clear whether a "required" form field is a "must-have" or an "optional".
- For a "must-have" form field, such as a username or a password form fields when you are registering a new account (for example), should you leave them empty, there will be some kind of prompt message as soon as you click "Next step" or "Save".
- For an optional form field, if it is left blank AND there is no "must-have" field form that is left blank at the same time, you should get no prompt message.

***When/how should the user be notified?***

- There are a few common scenarios, take Facebook registration page for example. **All fields, First name, Surname, Mobile number or email address, Re-enter mobile number or email address** and **New passwor**d are "must-have"s. A red exclamation mark will appear within a field form once you have interacted with it AND have left it blank; the field forms that have not been interacted with will not display any form of warning messages yet.
  [image]

All of field forms will display red exclamation marks if you have interacted with them AND have left them blank.
[image]

Use the popular online shopping website in New Zealand as a different example, 
"must-have" form fields such as **Your email address, Choose a password, Confirm password, Choose a user name, First name, Last name, Gender, Date of birth, Country**, they will not display any prompt messages if they are left blank.
[image]

They will only display prompt messages if the **Join Trade Me button** is clicked.

[image]

Apart from the two examples above, you will occasionally see a pop-up window as well should you leave any field form blank.

Answer (score 0):

If client side validation exists and the field is required you will usually be given a message (red, bold, *) by that field either on tabbing out (i.e. defocus) of the field or when you try to submit the form.

If only server side validation exists, the form will be submitted and then if the field is required, re-displayed to the client, ideally with markup (red, bold, *) that indicates the field is required.  Other field values already entered should be retained.

Answer (score 0):

> When/how should the user be notified?

That's usually a design decision.

Look to the following sources

- Requirements
- Specs
- A discussion with the designer and/or product owner
- Other company applications